# What's optimal from a cosmesis standpoint between applying a single or a double freeze-thaw cycle to treat a thick seborrhoeic keratosis?

Tags: dermatology, cryotherapy, cosmesis

I'm reading contradictory statements.

{2} states:

> Two freeze/thaw cycles (with a shorter freeze time) are more effective for thicker lesions such as seborrhoeic keratosis and warts.

However, {3} states:

> The treatment is repeated *in some cases*, once thawing has completed. This is known as a ‘double freeze-thaw’.

and {1} states that for warts, double freeze-thaw cycle confers little or no advantage over a single freeze in some location:

> The use of a double freeze-thaw cycle confers little or no advantage over a single freeze in the treatment of hand warts, but may be considerably more effective for plantar warts.

and {4} says that repeat freeze-thaw cycles generally are employed only in the treatment of malignancy:

> Slow thaw times and repeat freeze-thaw cycles produce more tissue injury than a single freeze and thaw. Usually, several minutes are allowed between repeat freeze-thaw cycles. Repeat freeze-thaw cycles generally are employed only in the treatment of malignancy.

What's optimal from a cosmesis standpoint between applying a single or a double freeze-thaw cycle to treat a thick seborrhoeic keratosis?

---

References:

- {1} https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/7857844/
- {2} https://dermnetnz.org/topics/liquid-nitrogencryotherapy-guidelines
- {3} [https://dermnetnz.org/topics/cryotherapy#:~:text=The%20nitrogen%20is%20applied%20to,'double%20freeze%2Dthaw'](https://dermnetnz.org/topics/cryotherapy#:%7E:text=The%20nitrogen%20is%20applied%20to,%27double%20freeze%2Dthaw%27).
- {4} https://www.aafp.org/afp/2004/0515/p2365.html